# ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'favicon.png' when DEBUG = False

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-static

raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'favicon.png' when DEBUG = False

I only get this error when DEBUG = False, I do not get any error when DEBUG = True

To fix this issue while keeping DEBUG = False, I must add back in favicon.png (which I had deleted a while back) to the static_root folder and then run python manage.py collectstatic

I checked all my files and all my html documents have the link favicon.png line commented out, so that is not the issue.

settings.py has the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root'),
]

VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

urls.py has following:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, I had just the same issue. Try to run `manage.py collectstatic`.
And by the way you should turn on logging in the console even if the DEBUG is set to False. There is a documentation article for that [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#examples).
And if you are not using different staticfiles storage on production, and running you staticfiles locally, you should probably remove `if settings.DEBUG:` from your urls.py.
Hope this helped!

Updated:
**Also** I've removed `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'` from `settings.py` in production version of my project.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below configuration settings to resolve the issue.

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['testnewapp.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'django_extensions',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

# Whitenoise Storage Class  - Apply compression but don’t want the caching behaviour
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

# Comment the below line
# django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

### Things to Remember

1. Make sure you’re using the static template tag to refer to your static files, rather that writing the URL directly. For example:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "images/error.jpg" %}" alt="OOps!" />

<!-- DON'T WRITE THIS -->
<img src="/static/images/error.jpg" alt="OOps!" />
```

2. If you get an error message with collectstatic, simply disable it by instructing Heroku to ignore running the manage.py collecstatic command during the deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry` so I decided to check the actual manifest of the staticfiles which is in a file named `staticfiles.json` in your staticfiles directory.

There you can see the actual entry for the path of the image you're looking for.

Example: my src in the img tag was `src="{% static '/images/logo-1.png' %}"`

and when I checked the json I found this entry:
`"images/logo-1.png": "images/logo-1.cb60e34d7e84.png",`

So I updated the src to `src="{% static 'images/logo-1.png' %}"` and it worked.